# Php Conditional statement : if database field equal "0.0" must hide to the page

Tags: php, conditional-statements

In my database i set some of my field into `decimal` so I can input numbers have decimal points.

and in my database even I don't input any in the input field always have a value of `0.0`.

in my case i don't want `0.0` to display in my page so i try this:

```
 <?php 
    if(!empty($current_orders["order_item"])){
        echo "<p>Credit Amount:  <span class=\"colorRed\">Php ". $current_orders["order_item"]."</span></p>";
    } else {
        echo null;
    }
  ?>
```

and it's not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not empty means those variable has value. empty means those variable is null. And 0.0 is a value. So, change your code to this :

```
<?php if($current_orders["order_item"] > 0.0){

  echo "<p>Credit Amount:  <span class=\"colorRed\">Php " 
   .  $current_orders["order_item"] . "</span></p>";

    } else {

    echo null;
  }

?>
```

Comment: it that possible negative value also display? example i have a value of `-1.5` is that possible to be display?

Comment: @jhunlio, just change > to ==

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bccomp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php) function in php for comparing float values.

Returns 0 if the two operands are equal, 1 if the left_operand is larger than the right_operand, -1 otherwise

```
<?php 
if(bccomp($current_orders["order_item"],0.0,1) == 0){
    echo "<p>Credit Amount:  <span class=\"colorRed\">Php ". $current_orders["order_item"]."</span></p>";
} else {
    echo null;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of this by using following code

```
$amount =   0.0;
if((!empty($amount)) && $amount>0){
    echo "<p>Credit Amount:  <span class=\"colorRed\">Php ". $amount."</span></p>";
} else {
    echo null;
}
```

If you want to display -ve values then just change the condition $amount>0 to $amount!=0, otherwise it will not display th -ve values